# Distance/measurement question! Help!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, unit-of-measure

There is a question in a book that I am trying to solve.

"A man usually rides his bike 1 kilometers per hour, yet the wind slows him to 6.76 kilometers for 26 minutes and 5.55 kilometers for 10. How long until he gets home 11.54 kilometers away?"

Thank you!

Comment: You probably lost a digit in his normal speed.  The $6.76$ and $5.55$ are probably km/hr.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  compute how far he travels in the first $26$ minutes.  You have his speed and the time.  Then compute how far he travels in the next $10$ minutes.  See how much distance is left.  Divide by his usual speed (probably greater than $1$ km/hr)to get the time it takes.  Watch out for minutes vs. hours.